# "must be str, not list" while trying scrape Yahoo Finance from an array

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm starting my learning journey in the Python programing therefore I'm facing basic error that I cant sort out why

The idea is to go thru the Array "stocks" and fetch their current price from Yahoo via web scraping

stocks =
0   GGBR4
1   MRVE3
2   TAEE11
3   MGLU3
4   HAPV3

My code:

```
#Workbook selection + sheet selection + range of stocks from the excel
workbook = gc.open_by_key('1DexwEtIPc2yA94QiWzWGR3ZZWo7YIZc00UX1CTMpdB8')
worksheet = workbook.worksheet('summary')
stocks = worksheet.get('stock_range')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(stocks)

for i in range(len(stocks)):
 symbol = stocks[i]
 url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '.SA'
 data = requests.get(url)
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
 price = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
```

The error message that I'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-fae00e25d5a8> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(stocks)):
      2   symbol = stocks[i]
----> 3   url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '.SA'
      4   data = requests.get(url)
      5   soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: can you show exactly what `stocks` is? Is it a string? List of strings? List of lists?

Comment: Just put a print statement before url line and see the value and type of symbol. `print(symbol, type(symbol))`. Also check if the list `stocks` is properly formatted  by printing it's value and type

Comment: It is not clear from your code what the value of the variable `stocks` is.  It is supposed to be a list of strings, but the error you're getting is indicating that it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your example with an adjustment in your stock list and it runs fine:

```
import requests
import bs4

stocks = ['GGBR4', 'MRVE3', 'TAEE11', 'MGLU3', 'HAPV3']

for i in range(len(stocks)):
  symbol = stocks[i]
  url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '.SA'
  data = requests.get(url)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
  price = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
```

However, you don't need to fetch indexes to run though a list.  The following method makes more sense, and is slightly more readable:

```
import requests
import bs4

stocks = ['GGBR4', 'MRVE3', 'TAEE11', 'MGLU3', 'HAPV3']

for symbol in stocks
  url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '.SA'
  data = requests.get(url)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
  price = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
```